# Guessing Game PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, shuffle

```
<?php

$strArray = array("supermarket", "programming", "development", "apache","university");

$index = isset($_POST['index']) ? $_POST['index'] : 0;
$message2 = str_shuffle($strArray[$index]);
if(!isset($_POST['guess'])){
    $message1="<h1>Welcome to the shuffle game!</h1></br>";
    $message2=str_shuffle($strArray[$index]);
}

elseif($_POST['guess'] == $strArray[$index]){   
    $message1="<h1>You guessed right!</h1></br>";
    $index++;
    $message2=str_shuffle($strArray[$index]);
}

elseif($_POST['guess'] != $strArray[$index]){
    $message1="<h1>You guessed wrong!</h1></br>";
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Guess the word!</title></head>
<body>

<?php echo $message1; echo "<b>Try to guess the shuffled word: </b>" . $message2; ?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<p><label for="guess">Enter your guess:</label>
<input type="text" id="guess" name="guess" /></p>
<input type="hidden" name="index" value="<?php echo $index; ?>">
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Guess</button>
</form></body></html>
```

The problem in this game is the index....

It starts with 0, and when it reaches the value 5 it gives an error because obviously the last value of the array is indexed as 4, so there is no index 5 in the array 
I tried to stop it with an if statement but it caused other errors!
Any solution?

[image: The Error]

Comment: You could try isset: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: What exactly is your expected behaviour when it reaches 5?

Comment: if post index greater that 5 , return false !

Comment: I want the index to reset to 0 after it reaches the value 4

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `$index` is too big by comparing it to the number of items in your array:

```
if ($index < count($strArray)) {
    // $index is valid
} else {
    // $index is too big
}
```

You need this check before incrementing `$index` when choosing the next shuffled string.

Your php logic could e.g. look like this:

```
<?php

$strArray = array("supermarket", "programming", "development", "apache","university");

$index = isset($_POST['index']) ? $_POST['index'] : 0;
$message2 = str_shuffle($strArray[$index]);
if(!isset($_POST['guess'])){
    $message1="<h1>Welcome to the shuffle game!</h1></br>";
    $message2=str_shuffle($strArray[$index]);
}

elseif($_POST['guess'] == $strArray[$index]){   
    $message1="<h1>You guessed right!</h1></br>";
    if ($index < count($strArray) - 1) {
        $index++;
    } else {
        $index = 0;
    }
    $message2=str_shuffle($strArray[$index]);
}

elseif($_POST['guess'] != $strArray[$index]){
    $message1="<h1>You guessed wrong!</h1></br>";
}

?>
```

(Side note: You should actually have this check also right at the beginning where you first define `$index`, together with a check for `>= 0` and a call to `is_numeric`. Otherwise a malicious user could send `$_POST['index']` as e.g. "100" or "-1" or "foo").

Answer (score 0):

Before displaying the game form, check if `$index` has reached the length of the array. If so, display a message saying that the game is over instead of the form.

```
<?php

$strArray = array("supermarket", "programming", "development", "apache","university");

$index = isset($_POST['index']) ? $_POST['index'] : 0;
$message2 = str_shuffle($strArray[$index]);
if(!isset($_POST['guess'])){
    $message1="<h1>Welcome to the shuffle game!</h1></br>";
    $message2=str_shuffle($strArray[$index]);
}

elseif($_POST['guess'] == $strArray[$index]){   
    $message1="<h1>You guessed right!</h1></br>";
    $index++;
    if ($index < count($strArray)) {
        $message2=str_shuffle($strArray[$index]);
    }
}

elseif($_POST['guess'] != $strArray[$index]){
    $message1="<h1>You guessed wrong!</h1></br>";
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Guess the word!</title></head>
<body>

<?php 
echo $message1; 
if ($index < count($strArray)) {
    ?>
    <b>Try to guess the shuffled word: </b>" <?php echo $message2; ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <p><label for="guess">Enter your guess:</label>
    <input type="text" id="guess" name="guess" /></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="index" value="<?php echo $index; ?>">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Guess</button>
    </form>
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
    <b>Game over!</b>
    <p><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">Play again</a></p>
    <?php
}
?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thaaaank you so much!!